# How to filter a pandas dataframe after groupby and mean

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter, group-by

Does anyone know off the top of their head how to filter after grouping a dataframe and applying the mean function?
I'd like to be able to get the `hour`s and `count`s for `day`s 0, 5, 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your groups are independent, filter **before** aggregation, else you compute the mean of the unwanted groups uselessly.

```
df[df['day'].isin([0, 5, 6])].groupby(['day', 'hour']).mean().round(2)
```

Comment: Sure, but I still don't know how to query the result. I need to get the actual hour and count values as lists for plotting. Is there a way to pull those out?

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output in your question?

Comment: print(g[g['day'] == 0]['count']), out: [621.67,
 544.88,
 453.2,
 318.25,
 206.02,
 114.94,
 61.92,
 35.75,
 21.48,
 14.72,
 35.59,
 80.2,
 216.06,
 411.06,
 603.24,
 718.9,
 760.75,
 768.02,
 705.14,
 590.12,
 469.82,
 394.82,
 356.0,
 354.71]

Comment: please provide a reproducible minimal input (i.e. no images!) and the matching expected output, this is currently not clear